# How does eUTXO model makes it possible to mint NFTs without smart contracts?

Tags: nft, eutxo

I am watching [a video by Coin Bureau](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0KhW8ftm90) and he mentioned that Cardano's eUTXO model makes it possible to mint NFTs without smart contracts.

Unfortunately he does not fully explain how so.

Any one care to explain, or can point to a resource that explains how the eUTXO model makes it possible to mint NFTs on Cardano without smart contracts?

Comment: Please refer to the answers to this question. https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-are-nfts-being-minted-without-smart-contract-in-cardano. In Cardano the native token (NFT is a subset of native token and is non-fungible). They are treated at par with ADA in almost all settings.

Answer (score 1):

Native tokens and NFTs were introduced with the Mary Hard Fork somewhere in March.

This could be a good start https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the link given above, which is great - I followed those instructions myself to mint tokens & NFTs - you can also check out the youtube that you can find here -> https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/technical-concepts/#unspent-transaction-output-utxo